# Reading a list of name to a SAS Macro

Tags: list, macros, sas

I am trying to read a list of values into a macro, so that the macro variable would contain the table name and create a column that would contain the table name.

My attempt, which is wrong, was trying to use the code below, and erroring out  because of the line " '&tbl' as Table_Dt ". The code below is inefficient, so feel free to enhance it. Thanks for your help.

```
%macro flat(tbl);
proc sql exec feedback stimer noprint outobs=5;
CREATE TABLE &tbl as
   SELECT 
            ID,
            DOB, 
            '&tbl' as Table_Dt
      FROM &tbl..flat_file;
QUIT;
%mend flat;
%flat(flat0113);
%flat(flat0213);
...
%flat(flat1213);
```

Answer (score 4):

As you are basically processing a list, this could also be done using call execute. No need to write all the information to macro variables. All tables/libraries are already stored in the sashelp tables and therefore are ready for list processing.

```
data _null_;
    set sashelp.vslib (where=(substr(libname,1,4) = 'FLAT'))  end =eof;
    if _n_ = 1 then call execute ('proc sql exec feedback stimer noprint outobs=5;');
    call execute ('
        CREATE TABLE '|| libname ||' AS
            SELECT  ID,
                    DOB,
                    "'||compress(libname)||'" as Table_Dt
                        FROM '||compress(libname)||'.flat_file
                    ;
                ');
    if eof then call execute ('QUIT;');
run;
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer. `call execute` is one of those little-used functions that can make things very convenient.

Answer (score 3):

Macros in quotation marks will only resolve with double quotes, not single. If you want to do a more efficient way, you can do so with the following modified code. I am assuming that you are reading from libraries named `flat0113`, `flat0213`, etc.

**Step 1: Get a list of all the libnames with the word "flat" in it**

```
proc sql noprint;
    select distinct libname
         , count(libname)
    into: tbl_list separated by ' '
        , total_tbls
    from sashelp.vmember
    where libname LIKE 'FLAT%'
    ;
quit;
```

This will create two macro variables: `&tbl_list`, and `&total_tbls`.

`&tbl_list` holds the values `flat0113 flat0213 flat ... flat1213`.

`&total_tbls` holds the total number of values in `&tbl_list`.

**Step 2: Loop through the newly created list**

```
%macro readTables;
    %do i = 1 %to &total_tbls;

        %let tbl = %scan(tbl_list, &i);

        proc sql exec feedback stimer noprint outobs=5;
            CREATE TABLE &tbl as
               SELECT 
                     ID,
                     DOB, 
                    "&tbl" as Table_Dt
               FROM &tbl..flat_file;
        quit;
    %end;

%mend;
%readTables;
```

This will read each individual value from `&tbl_list` one by one until the very end of the list.